# Drawing physical diagrams (particle spin)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, 3d, rotating

I'm trying to draw a particle and visualize the rotation of the particle. So far I have done this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\r{1.5} % Radius des Kreises
    \filldraw[top color=red,bottom color=green,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (\r); % Kreis
    \draw[thick,-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,\r) -- (0,2*\r) node[above] {$\vec{\mu}$}; % Pfeil durch die Mitte
    \draw[thick] (0,-1.5*\r) -- (0,-\r);
    \draw[thick,->] (-1.5*\r,0) to[bend right=45] (1.5*\r,0) node[below right] {$\vec{\omega}$}; % gebogener Pfeil
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which compiles e this picture:

[image: Magnetic moment of a proton]

However, I’m not satisfied with the arrow representing the rotation of the particle. I guess the start and endpoint of the arrow need to be changed to coordinates like (\r,135°) and (\r,45°) in order to look more like a three-dimensional drawing. However, since [Ti*k*Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) isn’t using polar coordinates, calculating the Cartesian coordinates doesn’t give me any output at all.

Is there an easy way to do this? Am I missing a crucial command here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!!

Answer (score 13):

It's better to use some 3d engine, for example Ti*k*Z `perspective` library.

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={30}{20}]
\draw[thick] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,-4);
\draw[
      top color=red,bottom color=green,
      %shading=ball,ball color=red % <-- alternative
     ] (0,0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,2) -- (0,0,4) node[above] {$\vec\mu$};
\draw[-latex] (180:3) arc (180:420:3)  node[above] {$\vec\omega$};
% uncomment to show the 3d plane
%\draw (-3.1,1) -- (-3.1,-3.1) -- (3.1,-3.1) -- (3.1,3.1) -- (1,3.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update 1:** A better-looking option (IMHO):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={30}{20}]
\draw[thick] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,-4);
\begin{scope}[blend group=screen]
  \draw[top color=red,bottom color=green] (0,0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw[shading=ball,ball color=red]      (0,0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{scope}
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,2) -- (0,0,4) node[above] {$\vec\mu$};
\draw[-latex] (180:3) arc (180:420:3)  node[above] {$\vec\omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Another one, separating upper and lower part of the sphere.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=180]
\draw[thick] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,-4);
\begin{scope}[blend group=screen]
  \draw[fill=red]   (-45:2) arc (-45:135:2) arc (0:180:2cm); 
  \draw[fill=green] (-45:2) arc (-45:135:2) arc (0:-180:2cm); 
  \draw[shading=ball,ball color=gray!30!black] (0,0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{scope}
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,2) node[right] {$N$} -- (0,0,4) node[above] {$\vec\mu$};
\draw[-latex] (-60:3) arc (-60:150:3)  node[above] {$\vec\omega$};
\node[right] at (0,0,-2.5) {$S$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks alot. Is there a manual explaining the syntax? Im not quite sure how I'd draw a new curved line based on your code. My idea was to split the circle in half
What I've done using my example is this:
```
\draw[thick] (-\r,0) to[line to,bend right=40]  (\r,0);
```
Then I'd want to fill the upper half red and the lower green. Ideally using shades.
How would the syntax look using the `perspective` library?

Comment: @Meck3l, you can look at the Ti*k*Z manual. The `perspective` library is discussed on p.738- (v3.1.9a)

Comment: Nice use of blend group! +1

Comment: @SandyG, thanks!!! :-D

Answer (score 11):

Without using any 3d tools, you can draw an arc using polar coordinates `(θ:r)` (note the colon for polar coordinates) for the start position and `arc(θ₁:θ₂:r)`. Then change `yscale` to make it an elliptical arc.

[image]

Also, lengthen the vector coming out of the north pole using `shorten <=` with a negative value.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\r{1.5} % Radius des Kreises
    \filldraw[top color=red,bottom color=green,draw=black,thick] (0,0) circle (\r); % Kreis
    \draw[thick,-{Latex[length=2mm]}, shorten <=-2mm] (0,\r) -- (0,2*\r) node[above] {$\vec{\mu}$}; % Pfeil durch die Mitte
    \draw[thick] (0,-1.5*\r) -- (0,-\r);
    \draw[thick,->, yscale=.3] (135:1.5*\r) arc(135:405:1.5*\r) node[above right] {$\vec{\omega}$}; % gebogener Pfeil
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** [Asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote_(vector_graphics_language)) with some palette. You can play with `nolight`, and the numbers in, for example,  `Rainbow(5)`

[image]

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import three;
import palette;
unitsize(1cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(3X+Z);
//currentlight=nolight;  // turn on or off

surface s=scale3(1.5)*unitsphere;
s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()));
draw(s);
draw(Label("$\vec{\omega}$",align=N,EndPoint),
     arc(O,-2X-2Y,2Y-2X,CW),black+.8pt,Arrow3);
draw(Label("$\vec{\mu}$",align=N,EndPoint),
     -3Z--3Z,black+.8pt,Arrow3);
```

[Asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote_(vector_graphics_language)) with uniform color.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import three;
unitsize(1cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(3,3,2);
real r=1.5;
draw(scale3(r)*unitsphere,green+opacity(.7));
draw(Label("$\vec{\omega}$",align=N,EndPoint),
     arc(O,2X-Y,2Y-X),black+.8pt,Arrow3);
draw(Label("$\vec{\mu}$",align=N,EndPoint),
     -3Z--3Z,black+.8pt,Arrow3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach, where I've used the `shadings` library, the other line of codes are simple and pretty similar to the above answers :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[thick] (0,-3)--(0,0);
\shade[top color=green, bottom color=red] (0,0)circle(1.5); 
\draw[thick] (0,0)circle(1.5); 
\draw[thick, ->] (0,1.45)--(0,3) node[left] {$\vec{\mu}$};
\draw[thick, ->] (180:1.75)arc[start angle=135, end angle=405, x radius=2.5cm, y radius =0.25cm] node[above right] {$\vec{\omega}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]